# Ember pod style component SCSS: variable undefined

Tags: ember.js, sass, ember-cli, ember-components

I am working on a pod-style ember app that uses `ember-cli-sass`, and `ember-component-css`.

I defined a variable in `app/styles/app.scss` that looks like this:

```
$yellow: #f2d173;
```

But when I try to use that variable in the scss file of a component located at: `app/components/login-form/styles.scss`, I get an error that reads:

```
Error: Undefined variable.
```

I would have expected the app.scss file to get loaded first, and for my variable to be accessible within my components - but something is not working perfectly.

Does any one know how to get application-wide scss/sass variables to be accessible in my components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a problem with including the file(s) / passing the var ...  **some more Infos about your project organization would help** ...

How do you organize/include your modules/files (`@import` or new rule `@use`)?
How is the file/dicrectory structure of your project?

If you work the traditional way with `@import` the order of importing the files/modules to the main file is important. You may check:

1. If `@import`:
   Is `.../login-form/styles.scss` imported to the main.scss AFTER the variable is set in `app/styles/app.scss`?

(If you are using ember pod style css files, you are probably importing your `login-form`'s styles from `@import "pod-styles";`, ensure that your variable definition is before that line!)

If you indeed work with new technique `@use` it is another way round and can be a little bit tricky. You may check:

2. If `@use`:
   Is the file where the variable is set (`app/styles/app.scss`) `@use`'d to `.../login-form/styles.scss` where you need the variable?
3. Alertnative if `@use`:
   If the module `app/components/login-form/styles.scss` is `@use`'d itself, did you pass your variable to the module when you `@use` it?

As `@use` is new, here ar some more infos about how it works: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use.

Comment: Because I was using ember pod components, my component's css was imported via `@import pod-styles;`. The issue ended being that I was defining my css variable AFTER I was calling: `@import "pod-styles";`. Your answer was right, but I'm going to modify it slightly to be more specific! Thank you for the help!

Comment: Well done and good that it's running now :-)